# Singularity of the given curve.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, singularity

Consider the curve $\gamma(t)=(t,{1\over t}),t\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$.Does,then does this curve have a singularity at some point?I suspect that it has none because only problem is at $0$ which is not in the domain of the variable $t$.So,I think the curve is regular as $|| \dot \gamma(t)||\neq 0$ for each $t\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Since $\gamma'(t) = (x'(t),y'(t))=(1,-t^{-2})$ can never equal to zero, the curve is regular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. It is a regular curve, since the derivative $\|(1,-1/t^2)\|\geq1$ is never zero.